# Right Click Items appears in grey boxes

Tags: windows, windows-8, colors, right-click

I am using Windows 8.1 64bit.  Suddenly **all** of my right click items are appearing in grey boxes. I don't know how this happened and i can't find any solution on the Web.

Images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try _Calibrate colour_ at next File Explore address `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display`?

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions will work:

1. Restart
2. Sign out and sign in